# Google map display markers by hours and location

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to implement a recovery community meeting finder. I have a database and map setup. I am trying to add a variable to display the current day's meetings that is also based upon a "nearest" location priority. How do I get the today's date variable in my database to selectively display only that days meetings? I'm using google maps api.

Thanks,

Terry

Answer (score 0):

In your database you have a datetime field that you store the date and time of the meetings I am guessing.

When you pull the information from your database to put in the map, simply use whichever apprrpriate sql language to select only those records that match the date you need.

This is actually more of a sql problem.

The closest location may not be catered for, but what you need to do is also a sql question. You need to add lat and long fields to your database and store the lat/longs for each of the meeting locations.

Then you can do a distance based sql search once you have those and the lat/long of the user.

Maps doesn't come into the selection process at all.

...
Edit.

The selecting by time is fairly simple but I thought I would share a distance based sql SELECT I used a while back. Note. It was used with MySQL but I think it should work with almost any sql db.

```
"SELECT name, tel, (((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS distance FROM takeaway WHERE active AND (((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) < 10 AND tel AND type = 'transport/taxi' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 5"
```

That gives you the basics for editing and reusing. Just remember to add the time/date check into your final string.